# What does it take to start producing(cultivating) probiotics?

Tags: bacteriology, gut-bacteria

Is there a DIY way? 
Is it possible to make a bacteria strain from scratch based on an existing one ? (for example lactobacillus reuteri).

Comment: have you looked elsewhere for potential ways?

Comment: Is "probiotic" a scientifically meaningful term?

Comment: you are right @jamesqf but I don't know the correct english word to refer to this commercial name...

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh yes I looked online but I didn't found nothing useful..

Comment: Probiotic prebiotic and synbiotic, are used to indicating health promoting bacteria, compounds that stimulate growth of probiotic bacteria relative to other bacteria and a mixture of both respectively.

Comment: @Alessandro Carrese: Don't feel bad.  I'm a native English speaker (and I think a fairly well educated one), yet I really have no idea what "probiotic" means beyond being a marketing term in the health food industry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a master's thesis involving enzymes from a probiotic bacteria. Many of the known probiotics were cultivated from faeces but others have also been isolated from breastmilk. Many of the probiotic bacteria are strict anaerobes and can only be succesfully cultivated in modified atmosphere. You may need to use selective plating with various prebiotic compounds such as Galactooligosaccharides or similar compounds in order to control bacterial growth. I recommend incubating at 37°C or slightly below depending on how well controlled your incubator is.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my spelling mistakes. I have a question about references... Is it allowed to self reference a peer reviewed article?